# Why on loosing aromatic chracter still product produced is 90% in the following reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-reduction

In Birch reduction reactant loses it aromatic chracter  but still the product found is to be 90%.
By loosing aromaticity product must be less stable so less amount of product must be formed. 
 Why still on loosing product found is to be 90%?

[image]

Comment: Because you're using sodium...

Comment: @Zhe What do you mean ?

Comment: Sodium / ammonia is very forcing conditions. Sure you lost aromaticity, but the sodium got to lose an electron.